# How to update a method?

Tags: java

```
public static TimeCard processTimeCard(String data)
{
   String[] split = data.split(",");
   String employee = split[0];
   String project = split[1];
   double rate = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);

   String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
                      "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",
                      "Saturday", "Sunday"};

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Get number of hours for each day of the week
   for (int index = 0; index < days.length; index++)
   {
       System.out.println("How many hours on " + days[index] + ".");
       double hours = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
   }


   // Create a TimeCard object and return a reference to it.
   return new TimeCard(employee, project, rate);
}
```

How can return hours as well? so that the last statement reads...

```
 return new TimeCard(employee, project, rate, hours);
```

Say that the number of days = 7
For Sunday hours entered = 2.... and so on for the rest of the days of the week, and in total the number of hours entered = 14. But how can I make sure that 14 is assigned to the hours variable so that I can return that value?

Answer (score 2):

First declare your `double hours` outside `for` loop, and then also add a new constructor.

```
double hours = 0;

for (int index = 0; index < days.length; index++)
{
     System.out.println("How many hours on " + days[index] + ".");
     hours = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
}

// Create a TimeCard object and return a reference to it.
   return new TimeCard(employee, project, rate, hours);
```

Create a new constructor woth `hours` as argument,

```
public TimeCard(Employee employee, Project project, double rate, double hours) {
 // Constructor implemenetation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can return hours as well? so that the last statement reads...

You will have to create a new constructor that taeks hours as argument.

```
public TimeCard(Employee employee, Project project, double rate, int hours){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify or create the `TimeCard` constructor such way so that you can pass hours also as a parameter into the constructor.

```
public TimeCard(Employee employee, Project project, double rate, double hours){
  //Logic for your operation
}
```